# ¿Cómo puedo reducir este código? (ARDUINO)

Tags: c++, arduino

**El problema es el siguiente:** Crear un paso peatonal en Arduino, habrá 3 semáforos acomodados de la siguiente forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando el led rojo del semáforo 3 se encienda el led verde del semáforo 1 y 2 se pondrá en verde, los tres semáforos deberán de pasar a amarillo al mismo tiempo.

El código que llevo hasta ahora es el siguiente:

```
int rojo1 = 9;
int amarillo1 = 8;
int verde1 = 7;

int rojo2 = 13;
int amarillo2 = 12;
int verde2 = 11;

int rojo3 = 5;
int amarillo3 = 4;
int verde3 = 3;

void setup () {
  pinMode(rojo1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(amarillo1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(verde1, OUTPUT);
  
  pinMode(rojo2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(amarillo2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(verde2, OUTPUT);
  
  pinMode(rojo3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(amarillo3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(verde3, OUTPUT);
}

void loop () {

  digitalWrite(rojo1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(verde1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(rojo2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(rojo3, HIGH);
  
  delay(3000);
  
  digitalWrite(rojo2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(rojo3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(verde1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(amarillo1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(amarillo2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(amarillo3, HIGH);
  
  delay(1000);
  
  digitalWrite(amarillo1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(amarillo2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(amarillo3, LOW);
  
  digitalWrite(rojo1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(verde2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(verde3, HIGH);
 
  delay(3000);
  
  digitalWrite(rojo1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(verde2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(verde3, LOW);
  
}
```

Lo que busco es poder simplificar el código lo más posible

Comment: ¿El código que publicas implementa el ciclo completo de los semáforos o faltan operaciones de encendido/apagado?

Answer (score 0):

## Simplificación del problema

Viendo toda la repetición de acciones, se me ocurrió que quizás abstrayendo un poco y creando una función para encender o apagar un arreglo de leds, podrías ahorrar líneas y simplificarlo, aunque luego de escribirlo, no estoy seguro si hemos *simplificado* el código. Lo que sí, si tienes que hacer cambios en los tiempos, o en las secuencias, probablemente sea más fácil hacerlo en esta versión que en la original que planteas. El lado negativo es que no te puedes descuidar con el tamaño de arreglos en este lenguaje. En fin, no sé si es una *"simplificación"* o realmente una *"mejora"*, pero es un enfoque más abstracto.

## Código

```
int rojo1 = 9;
int amarillo1 = 8;
int verde1 = 7;

int rojo2 = 13;
int amarillo2 = 12;
int verde2 = 11;

int rojo3 = 5;
int amarillo3 = 4;
int verde3 = 3;

int todosLosLeds[] = {rojo1, amarillo1, verde1, rojo2, amarillo2, verde2, rojo3, amarillo3, verde3};
int secuencia1[] = {verde1, rojo2, rojo3};
int secuencia2[] = {rojo1, verde2, verde3};
int amarillos[] = {amarillo1, amarillo2, amarillo3};

int tiempoNormal = 3000;
int tiempoAmarillos = 1000;

void setup () {
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    pinMode(todosLosLeds[i], OUTPUT);
  }
}

void loop () {
  encender(secuencia1, 3);
  delay(tiempoNormal);
  apagar(secuencia1, 3);
  encender(amarillos, 3);
  delay(tiempoAmarillos);
  apagar(amarillos, 3);
  encender(secuencia2, 3); 
  delay(tiempoNormal);
  apagar(secuencia2, 3);
}

void apagar(int *leds, int count) {
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    digitalWrite(leds[i], LOW);
  }
}

void encender(int *leds, int count) {
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    digitalWrite(leds[i], HIGH);
  }
}
```